# refresh a part of the activity

Tags: android

In my activity I have the 15% of the screen for login, it's a TextView and a button:

```
    <TextView               
        android:id="@+id/registered_text"
        android:color = "@color/white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"   
        ></TextView>

        <Button
        style="@style/myButton" 
        android:id="@+id/reg_button" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"    
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    >
    </Button>
```

The textView value and the Button text and listener depends on the user is register or not:

```
    loginDB login = new loginDB(context);
    Cursor cursor = login.logData(new String[]{"userJoomla", "idUSER", "name","email"});

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        userJoomla = cursor.getInt(0);
        userID = cursor.getInt(1);
        name = cursor.getString(2);
        email = cursor.getString(3);

        greeting.setText("Hola " + name);
        loginLogout.setText("Desconectarme");

        loginLogout.setOnClickListener(logout);
    } else {  
        name = "usuario móvil";
        greeting.setText("");
        loginLogout.setText("Identificarme");
        loginLogout.setOnClickListener(newLogin);
    }

    login.close();
```

How can I refresh it when a user login or logout?

Thank you in advance

Comment: what do you want to refresh? Do you want to swap whole screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what exactly do you want to do. Do you just want to change some text of a button or replace your complete screen?

Changing the button caption is pretty simple. In your onClickListener do the same as you already did:

```
loginLogout.setText("some new text");
```

If you want to change the whole screen you can react on login/logout in two ways.
Either you start a new activity after login was sucessfull and finish the current activity when logout was sucessfull

or you use Fragments. (the better way)

[Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) are "more or less" the same things like activities in activities. An activity can contain multiple fragments. You can replace, add and remove fragments during runtime. Thats how you can swap your whole screen or just parts of it.

Use the [Compatibility Library](http://source.android.com/compatibility/index.html) to use Fragments on devices < Honeycomb

Comment: I havn't known about fragments, but they are just what I was looking for! thanks!